# What is the most secure HTML5 video format?

Tags: html, security, html5-video

Little background. My work was recently bought by another company. New company is very security cautious since they were recently audited. I create training videos for our clients that we host on our web server. The new owners don't allow MP4 files on their server because there is a possibility for malicious code to be injected. I was going to use wmv because this is allowed but my understanding is HTML5 doesn't easily cooperate with wmv (Spent a long time trying to figure out why my video tags weren't working).

So my question is. What video format is secure and compatible with at least IE, but preferably Chrome and FireFox. I'm guessing that if it is compatible with HTML5 then it should work with any modern browser.

Comment: The new owners are crazy.  If you don't trust the files on your server, _don't put them on the server_.  Limiting the file types will do very little.

Comment: The only "security issues" with video formats are that a malicious video may inject code if it finds a vulnerability in a specific video player on the client.  If you control the video, you can make sure it isn't malicious.

Comment: From the title of your post, I assumed you were concerned about DRM issues. I don't understand how putting mp4 files on your server is a security risk. Are they worried about the security of the server itself? Or about hosting malware that will get pushed to users via mp4 files?